# SyntaxError that I'm not seeing in this Ruby code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When trying to access a page of my practice webapp(via localhost), I'm getting an error of

`syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ';' or '\n'`

and it's supposedly on line 4 of this file. There is no ":" colon in the code. Line4 is: @contact = Contact.new

What am I not understanding? This is within a Controller.rb file

```
class ContactsController < ApplicationController 

  def new
    @contact = Contact.new
  end

  def create
    @contact = Contact.new(secure_params)
    if @contact.valid?

      flash[:notice] = "Message sent from #{@contact.name}." 
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      render :new
    end 
  end

  private
  def secure_params
    params.require(:contact).permit(:name, :email, :content)
  end 
end
```

As far as I can tell, this is the full error:

```
SyntaxError at /contacts/new

syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ';' or '\n'
```

Comment: Line 3, 4, and 5:  `def new
@contact = Contact.new
end`

Comment: post your contacts_controller.rb file

Comment: add it to the question so we can actually read it? And add the full error, because I suspect that isnt it

Comment: that's not the full error. Please add the backtrace either from your browser window, or from your console.

Comment: Ugh. Sorry guys, I cannot get this Markdown to ever work right for me.

Comment: You've lost me on "backtrace". Not sure what that means. This is what I'm seeing when I try to access localhost/contacts/new   http://imgur.com/HCLygSw

Comment: Post the entire error message, you will by default then have posted the backtrace.

Comment: That is the only error I get. That image I posted in the above comment is what happens when I try to access the page. Is there somewhere else I'm supposed to be getting errors? When I check Chrome dev tools, it shows that localhost/contacts/new throws a 500 Internal Server Error. Does that help at all?

Comment: I think you are missing `end` in the end of the controller

Comment: So there is nothing blatantly obvious about why line 4 is specifically mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

It was actually an error in the contact.rb file within the Models directory. The Better Errors page that popped up really didn't help me, as a beginner. When I remembered to look at the apps logs directory, I saw this: `SyntaxError - /Users/NormalUse/ror/learn-rails/app/models/contact.rb:1: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ';' or '\n'` and I ended up having an extra blank, space in the code in one of the lines. Thanks for replies. As a beginner, It's sort of frustrating being down voted like I was, but at the same time I can see why the original question was hard for others to help with.